# Как поставить модуль Python?

Tags: python, package

Подскажите как поставить модуль (библиотеку) Python в Windows?

Слышал, надо `install setup.py`

Вводил и в интерпретаторе, и в CMD, но нет такой команды, пытался команду `python` - результат тот же. Видимо, эти команды только для Linux. Так как же все-таки установить библиотеку в Windows?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html

Comment: Я же написал - мне не понятно, как там объясняют, можете сами объяснить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Открываешь консоль (cmd.exe), переходишь в папку, где у тебя лежит setup.py с помощью команды cd, когда перейдешь набирай `python setup.py` - вот, по идее, и всё. Да, кстати, python.exe должен быть в переменной PATH, чтобы ты мог запускать его в любой папке.

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы он был в переменной PATH?

Comment: Дебе надо указать путь до python.exe на твоем компе Как это сделать в виндоус, можешь посмотреть например здесь: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: Так, что вы можете помочь?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-to-add-python-to-the-windows-path (текст)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7 (картинка) И да, учись гуглить, особенно в питоне без англоязычных ресурсов ты далеко не уедешь ;)

Comment: я бы добавил 
python setup.py install
А то у setup.py могут быть разные параметры

Comment: пакеты, установленные с помощью `python setup.py install` не всегда можно чисто удалить (нет команды `uninstall`), поэтому следует использовать `pip`, который имеет команду uninstall (и много других полезных свойств таких как: использование безопасных соединений и кэширование, что позволяет  быстро воспроизвести идентичное окружение -- быстро переставить установленные пакеты).

Answer (score 8):

Можно и проще, с помощью [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/) и [easy install](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools).

Кратко говоря, это менеджеры пакетов python, которые сами разруливают зависимости и делают много полезных вещей.

Answer (score 2):

Я делал так: в командную строку виндовс вводил путь к установщику пип, пробел, инсталл, имя файла  (путь к установщику может быть разный)

```
C:\Python34\Scripts\pip3.exe install имя-пакета
```